# How do I make PHP count the number of thumbnails in a row using bootstrap?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, count

```
    <?php if($userinfo->num_rows == 0)
    echo ("<p style='color: #f00;'>No users in this department<p>");
    else{
    $x = 0;
    echo '<ul class="thumbnails">';
    while($userDetail = $userinfo->fetch_assoc()){
    $x ++;
    echo '
    <li class="span3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user'.$x.'"><img class="default"                                            src="'.$userDetail['photo'].'" alt="" /></a>
    <div class="caption">
    <h5>'.$userDetail['first'].' '.$userDetail['last'].'</h5>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user'.$x.'">View Details</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </li>
    (other code)
```

This is a bootstrap thumbnail. I need PHP to count 4 users in one row and then star ta new row of users. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [modulus](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to find out if the current thumbnail is the last in a row of four:

```
$is_last_of_four = $x % 4 === 0;
```

You can use this result to insert additional markup that ends the current row and starts a new one.

Comment: So exactly how would I incorporate that into my code?